# What is the best way to validate RTSP stream URL [python]

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm search for the best way to decide whether RTSP stream is good or not with metrics about the stream.
The answer not must to be True/False.
I imagine that service as function that get url for stream and return statistics and answer if the stream is good or not.
for Example: `def validate(stream_url: string, test_duration: int)`

Answer (score 0):

little late but we try use pyav with open method you can open a stream inspect some information about the stream or in case of an error you can catch them

br